# Moved config, entity and other classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a big problem.
I have an application with Spring-Boot and Spring-Data. 
It goes well before that i moved some classes and refactory the directory.

I have two database and before i moved classes, i had this config class for a second database:

```
         @Configuration
      @EnableTransactionManagement
      @EnableJpaRepositories(
         basePackages="it.phoops.rt.grigliaprocessi.util", 
         entityManagerFactoryRef = "organoEntityManager",
         transactionManagerRef = "organoTransactionManager")     
      public class OrganoConfig {

          @Bean(name = "organoDataSource")
           @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="organo.datasource")
          public DataSource organoDataSource(){
                  return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
           }

          @Bean(name="organoEntityManager")
          public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean    
       organoEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
         @Qualifier("organoDataSource") DataSource dataSource){

          return       
 builder.
 dataSource(organoDataSource()).
 packages("it.phoops.rt.grigliaprocessi.util.entity").
  persistenceUnit("organo").build();
 }

           @Bean("organoTransactionManager")

                public PlatformTransactionManager 
 organoTransactionManager()               
 {     
                      return new   
  DataSourceTransactionManager(organoDataSource());
        }

 }
```

Now, i moved in "it.phoops.rt.grigliaprocessi.organo" and i change the value of "basePackages" from "it.phoops.rt.grigliaprocessi.util" to "it.phoops.rt.grigliaprocessi.organo"  and
the string "it.phoops.rt.grigliaprocessi.util.entity" to it.phoops.rt.grigliaprocessi.organo.entity".

I moved Entity, Service and Repository classes from:

```
it.phoops.rt.grigliaprocessi.util.controller
it.phoops.rt.grigliaprocessi.util.entity
it.phoops.rt.grigliaprocessi.util.repository
```

to

```
it.phoops.rt.grigliaprocessi.organo.controller
it.phoops.rt.grigliaprocessi.organo.entity
it.phoops.rt.grigliaprocessi.organo.repository
```

But now, i have this error, caused of nested exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: 
class it.phoops.rt.grigliaprocessi.organo.entity.Albero
```

......

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:   
 Error creating bean with name 'alberoRepository': Invocation of init 
 method failed; nested exception is 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
 Not a managed type: class 
 it.phoops.rt.grigliaprocessi.organo.entity.Albero
```

....

```
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error 
creating bean with name 'alberoService': Unsatisfied dependency 
expressed through field 'repo'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating 
bean with name 'alberoRepository': Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed 
type: class it.phoops.rt.grigliaprocessi.organo.entity.Albero
```

....

```
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error 
creating bean with name 'alberoController': Unsatisfied dependency 
expressed through field 'alberoService'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error 
creating bean with name 'alberoService': Unsatisfied dependency 
expressed through field 'repo'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating 
bean with name 'alberoRepository': Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed 
type: class it.phoops.rt.grigliaprocessi.organo.entity.Albero
```

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change you basepackages declaration from it.phoops.rt.grigliaprocessi.util to it.phoops.rt.grigliaprocessi.organo. Also please check the basepackages in componentScan in your Spring boot main class.

Comment: I have already changed basepackages declaration from:      
       it.phoops.rt.grigliaprocessi.util 
to: 
      it.phoops.rt.grigliaprocessi.organo.